# Text, Tags, base64 and RegEx C#

Tags: c#, regex

Good evening, I Have a Regex problem.

I read a json and the text has a structure as:

```
text[TAG1 attributes]othertext[/TAG1][TAG2 attributes]base64string[/TAG2]
```

I need to extract the final text as

`text othertext base64string(decode)`

The input text can be multi line.

What can I do to get this?

Thanks!

Comment: The tick of the accepted answer indicates that it is solved (yes, this is visible from the list of questions). I would argue that this question could use a better title, however adding "[SOLVED]" is not the kind of improvement I would have in mind. And that explains why I rolled back that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Regex that should match your case:

```
(?>^|\n|\[[^\]\n]*\]\n*)(?'content'[^\[]+)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWtmm4/1)

You basically match `[` or `newline` and anything between, up to an `]` and start to capture in a **group** named **content**, the *content* until the next `[` occurrence.

In `C#` it would look something like this:

```
        var input = @"text[TAG1 attributes]othertext[/TAG1][TAG2 attributes]base64string[/TAG2]
text2[TAG1 attributes]othertext2[/TAG1][TAG2 attributes]base64string2[/TAG2]
text3[TAG1 attributes]othertext3[/TAG1][TAG2 attributes]base64string3[/TAG2]";

        var expression = new Regex(@"(?>^|\n|\[[^\]\n]*\]\n*)(?'content'[^\[]+)");
        Match match = expression.Match(input);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            var content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
```

[.Net fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Td91MH)

Read on MS docs about [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I resolve in this way with your RegEX

```
    foreach (Match match in items)
{
    string content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) == false)
    {
        try
        {
            var decodeText = TextHelper.Base64Decode(content);
            sb.AppendLine(decodeText);
        }
        catch
        {
            sb.AppendLine(content);
        }
    }
```

I hope to help someone with this snippet based on your solution